# Can I track why a user didn't install our Outlook add-in?

Tags: outlook-web-addins, office-store

Can I track why a user didn't install our Outlook add-in because of Microsoft features for IT Admin ? For example, the user can't install add-in with following situations. My team want to track it and set next actions for acquisitions.

- Example1: IT admin disables App Store from office client, but a user see our add-in in App Source web page. The user try to install it, but finally he/she can't install it.
- Example2: IT admin doesn't allow users to install add-in before they approve it, even though the user can see our app.

I don't know all cases when a user can't install our add-in by IT admin's policy, so I just wrote what I could imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the feature to track the why user didn't install add-in is not a part of the product.We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.
Can you tell us how do you plan to use this information?

Comment: Sure, let me submit idea in user-voice.